# Rails : carrier wave : validate before file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, carrierwave

I am using Rails and carrierwave to upload a photo . I need to check if the user filled the file field or not before pressing submit.
In another words I want to prevent the user from submitting before uploading and I need it 
to be client side (not by rails validations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add simple client-side html validation, like *required*, for example

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label "Upload" %><br>
 <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'form-control', :required => true %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , It was perfect.
I can't believe it was that easy.